# Is the domain of a derivative always the same as the domain of the original function?

Tags: derivatives, singularity

I have seen similar if not the same questions, but none of them fully answer this question.

---

For  my question, I want to know why I would need to rationalize the denominator of $\frac {3y} {2 \sqrt y}$ *to* $\frac {3 \sqrt y} 2$, when writing out the derivative for $h(y) = y\sqrt y$.  In another similar case for $\frac {1} {2 \sqrt x}$ *to* $\frac {\sqrt x} {2 \ x}$, for the derivative of y = √x, there is no need to rationalize the denominator of  its derivative; in other words, the domain of its derivative is different from the original function, regardless if I rationalize the denomiantor or not. So what is the purpose of rationalizing the denominator?

Note:

-The domain of the derivative of h(y) is [0,∞) when leaving it as $\frac {3y} {2 \sqrt y}$

- The domain of the derivatibe of h(y) is (0,∞) when rationalizing the denominator to $\frac {3 \sqrt y} 2$
- The domain of h(y) is [0,∞)

---

For those who still don't understand my question:

For h'(y), why would I need to rationalize the denominator? How would I know that the domains of h and h' are the same in the first place? From initial calculation of the derivative, it gives $\frac {3y} {2 \sqrt y}$, where x at 0 is undefined

Comment: Generally, you rationalize the denominator of a quantity only if you are going to do subsequent calculations using it.

Comment: The question seems to be about something much narrower that the content of the discussion, but at face value, not only is the statement false, it can fail completely: The Weierstrass function is the standard example of a function that is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: do guys know the point of rationalizing the denominator of h'(y)? Why can't I leave the answer as is with radical in the denominator?

Comment: It's a good thing to note that $y\sqrt{y}=y^{\frac32}$.  Finding the derivative then using the power rule will eliminate whatever doubt you have.

Comment: A stretch:  you are basically arguing why we shouldn't write functions in the form $y=\frac{f(x)\cdot g(x)}{g(x)}$ as opposed to the simpler $y=f(x)$.

Comment: If it's that I can see why it's better to leave it as y = f(x). But in some of my textbooks, I've seen answers written with a radical at the bottom, while the derivative of h(y) is to simplify where there's no radical at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

For $y = \sqrt x$, it is clear that the derivative is not defined at x=0 because y'= $\frac {1} {2 \sqrt x}$ will result in $\frac {1} {0}$, and to double check  $\frac {\sqrt x} {2 \ x}$ still makes the derivative undefined x=0 resulting in $\frac {0} {0}$. So in either case, you have a 0 in the denominator, in other words resulting in division by 0, which makes the function undefined at x = 0.

---

For h(y), it is a different case. You calculate h'(y) as:

$\frac {3y} {2 \sqrt y}$ *or* $\frac {3 \sqrt y} 2$

For $\frac {3y} {2 \sqrt y}$, you get a $\frac {0} {0}$ case, but when rationalizing the denominator to $\frac {3 \sqrt y} 2$, you get $\frac {0} {2}$, which is 0, so it is defined at 0. So in brief, from my way to look at it this is to view the step of "rationalzing the denomiantor" as a second check as to whether the derivative is really undefined at x = 0.

- Thus, the domain for h'(y) is [0,∞), as x at 0 of the derivative IS defined, so include it in the domain.

Comment: Thanks! I think I sort of understand now but is it necessary to leave answers with radicals in the denominator?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it contains a couple of statements that appear to me to be incorrect.  The function $\ h(y)=y\sqrt{y}=y^\frac{3}{2}\ $ is defined for *all* non-negative $\ y\ $, so its domain is $\ [0,\infty)\ $, not $\ (0,\infty)\ $ (unless, for some reason you want to restrict it artificially to the latter interval).

The function $\ h\ $ is differentiable on $\ (0,\infty)\ $, but *not* at $\ y=0\ $. While it does have a *right* derivative there, it has no left derivative, because $\ h(y)\ $ is undefined for $\ y < 0\ $.

*Both* of the expressions $\ \frac{3y}{2\sqrt{y}}\ $ and $\ \frac{3\sqrt{y}}{2}\ $ are correct ways to write the derivative of $\ h\ $, as long as you keep in mind that they're only valid for $\ y>0\ $.  While $\ \frac{3y}{2\sqrt{y}}\ $ is undefined at $\ y=0\ $, this isn't a problem because the derivative doesn't exist there anyway.  Also, while $\ \frac{3\sqrt{y}}{2}\ $ is a little simpler, and seems to me to be a more natural way to write the derivative, it is certainly not *mandatory* for you to write it that way.

**Reply to query from OP in comments below**

The difference between the two cases is that, in the first, one of the two equivalent expressions (namely $\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\ $) has a non-zero numerator and a zero denominator, so it's going to remain undefined at $\ x=0\ $ no matter how you write it.

In the second case, however, one of the two *not quite* equivalent expressions (namely $\ \frac{3\sqrt{y}}{2}\ $) has a zero numerator and non-zero denominator, and therefore has a well-defined value of $\ 0\ $ at $\ y=0\ $.  But if you then multiply it by *any* expression of the form $\ \frac{f(y)}{f(y)}\ $ where $\ f(0)=0\ $ (and, in particular, by $\ \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{y}}\ $), the resulting expression will be undefined at $\ y=0\ $, and therefore have a different domain from the original.

Comment: Yes that was a typo. domain of h(y) should be [0,∞)

Comment: While two of the expressions are the same, how is it possible that one's domain is different from the other when having a rationalized denominator? For example y' of √x is 1 / 2√x, same as √x/ 2x, the domain still the same not affected in any way. But for h'(y) the domain is affected/changed when having the denominator rationalized. Why is this?